# Cache header files for make/g++

Tags: c++, linux, caching, makefile, g++

I am working on a large C++ code base and I want to speed up its compilation times. One thing I know is that all of my library includes are on a network drive which slows down things a lot. If I can get make or something else to automatically cache them, either in /tmp, or to a ramdisk, I expect that to improve the compile times for me quite a bit. Is there a way to do that? Of course I can copy them manually and set up a sync job but then every developer will have to do that on every box they ever compile so I am looking for an automated solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Copying them manual might not be that bad. In fact it might be the right thing to do if you are able to set up some kind of version control system like SVN. Then you can checkout once and update/commit per need. This way you also get a good management of different versions of the files.

Comment: Check this. [similar question on super user][1]


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/446695/transparently-cache-files-from-a-network-drive-in-linux

Answer (score 1):

Of course.  There are lots and lots of ways.  You can just have a make rule that copies things then have people run `make copylocal` or whatever.  This is fast but people have to remember to do it, and if the libraries change a lot this could be annoying.  You can make a rule that copies things then put it as a prerequisite to some other target so it's done on every build, first.  This will take longer: will the copy step plus using local copies take longer total time than just using the remote copies?  Who knows?

You could also use a tool like ccache to locally cache the *results* of the compilation, rather than copying the library headers.  This will give you a lot more savings for a typical small incremental build and it's easily integrated into the build system, but it will slightly slow down "rebuild the world" steps to cache the objects.

Etc.  Your question is too open-ended to be easily answerable.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using network file systems for code. Use a [version control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) like [git](http://git-scm.com/).

You might also consider using [ccache](http://ccache.samba.org/).